# Каким способом можно сделать продвинутый autocomplete?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Надо сделать автодополнение, который будет дополнять СЛОВА, которые могут быть не первыми в форме, как в гугле - вводишь слово, и сразу выскочит дополнение к нему.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите как работает компонент [Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) вот на [этом сайте](https://jewelry-catalog.ru/). Отдельные слова (к примеру кольцо, золото и т.д.) склеиваются и получается поисковый запрос вида поисковой системы.

Comment: там автозаполнение работает только если вводить слово сначала, а мне надо именно в любом месте запроса, даже если пару слов введено и вы вводите *золото* то чтоб появлялась подсказка к нему

Comment: а, стоп что-то не досмотрел, щас просмотрю)

Comment: @shumik_UA введите `той` и увидите что автокомплит выдаст теги найдя в конце буквы, просто поиск как я описал выше осуществляется по тегам а не по строкам текста, по этому и вывод короткий.

Comment: на самом сайте форма не работает)